# Is using -O3 with emscripten considered safe?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, emscripten

Older version of emscripten (i.e. pre fastcomp) when run with the `-O3` flag spewed the following warning:

> WARNING  : Applying some potentially unsafe optimizations! (Use -O2 if this fails.)

However, newer versions when run with `-O3` don't warn at all.

Does this mean that using `-O3` is now safe?

Comment: You should also make sure to test your code with -Os (instead of -O3), which optimizes for size.  In some cases I've found it to be faster than -O3, most likely due to cache performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. It runs some slower but more powerful optimizations than -O2, but none of them are unsafe. See `emcc --help` for more details on what it does.